# Src v/s Binary?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

Quite a basic question but can someone tell me the difference between downloading src files against downloading binary files?

Comment: @Suroot : I meant in this page :- http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/ver.php?fid=167 what is the difference if I download binaries v/s downloading source

Comment: The binary version would be the compiled libraries whereas the source files would indicate that you are going to have to compile it yourself.  In almost all cases you're just going to want the binary (library) files as you probably don't need to recompile the library from scratch.  Usually the source indicates that you want to change something in the file to customize it for your specific application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Source files are uncompiled C/C++ code, while binary files are the compiled programs.

Comment: (Nitpick) Source files aren't limited to C and C++ code. They can be any language.

Comment: I know, but this question was C/C++ specific. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about an open-source program that you can download as either source files or as a binary distribution. The difference is pretty clear. YOU will have to compile the source files if you want to use the program (which may or may not be easy depending on the program and its dependencies, and other factors). The advantage of the source download is that you have all the sources for the application, so, if you have the skill and motivation, you can edit the code to either solve bugs or extend functionality, or you can pick out some parts of the code for your own use in another project (assuming you follow the license restrictions).

If you download the binary, then all you can do is use the program, but if that is all you need, then do that, don't bother download and compiling the source code. Of course, if you have an unusual platform, it could happen that there is no downloadable binary that will run (properly) on your platform, in which case, compiling from source is your best bet (but it rarely is very easy to compile someone else's code without having pretty good programming experience).

Answer (score 0):

Source files are the files that programmers or software engineers work with to build a computer program.  Another development tool (also a program) called a compiler takes those source files and turns them into an executable file that you can run on a computer.

If you download the source, you need a development environment to compile it into an executable to run.

If you download the executable, as long as it's compatible with your computer, you can just run it.